# Auto Populate Access Form Based on Name Selection

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Let me preface this with the fact that I know I don't know much about access. I took a single class in college and that has essentially made me the most "qualified" where I work to make this temporary solution.

I am trying to make a database for internal use at my organization and I am fairly certain I am not doing it properly.

I currently have a table called Users and Computers that contains customer names, phone number, computer names, desk, room and building number. Additionally I have the primary key as an auto generated number which realistically serves no purpose.

I have an additional table that will be called "Tickets" which I would like to be populated with a form. The Tickets table contains similar entries, name, phone number, computer names, building, room, desk. The tickets table also has a primary key called "Ticket Number." I would like to make a form that displays the ticket number, which I have working, and below that has a user name combo box that drops down and the user name can be selected. (I also have this part working.)

Once the user name is selected I would like to have all additional fields populated based on the record. So essentially if Joe selects his name it will put the phone number, computer names, desk, building, room etc. into the form for him. Then the user would just need to fill out whatever issue they are having. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Also I am sure I am not following best practices and am open to fixing this to do it properly if I should set up the tables differently etc.

P.S. Access might not be best for this and I plan is to eventually use JIRA but the infrastructure isn't available to me nor the funding at this organization to purchase the software right now.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to store any of that duplicated information, simply the unique UserID in the ticket and link the user table back to display it, NOT store it. That's the point of the "serves no purpose" autonumber. Simply store that not the users name , age , phone number etc etc over and over again.

Comment: The information being duplicated would actually be useful to the organization for analytical purposes. E.G. how many tickets were opened on this computer name. 

As for the UserID I can definitely see doing that but the user won't know the ID generated by access. How can I have the form pull the entire record based on the user name/ID and populate the appropriate fields?

Comment: I managed to get the auto populate to work by changing the first combo box to collect all information from the record I wanted. I then added an after event to the combo box. So for me I have the primary key as column 0, user name as column 1 and phone number as column 2. The user only sees the user names when they drop down the user combo box. Thus an example of my after event code is: "Me.[Phone Number] = Me.cmbUserName.Column(2)" I tried this multiple times before but each time it either didn't work or the form went completely blank. I still cant get this to work with multiple fields.

Comment: Agree with Minty. Do not duplicate data. Build query that joins tables to retrieve related data. This is main concept of relational database. Could use form/subform arrangement. User info on main form, related tickets in subform. Getting multi-column combobox to work is another issue.